# Redirect with www not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently switched from a shared hosting to a VPS.
Everything is working fine and I can access al of my domains.

But I seem to have 1 problem:
In the past all non-www url's where redirected to url's with www.

I did this with the following htaccess.txt code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.tx3\.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.tx3.be/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I'm using a new htaccess at the time with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^off(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But both are not working on redirecting my non-www domain.

When I visit my non-www domain, I get the following page:
"Apache is functioning normally"

I tried using the DirectAdmin redirect for redirecting the non-www domain to a domain with www, but that also didn't work.

Maybe I've got it all wrong and it wasn't a htaccess problem in the first place.

Did I forget something in my server settings?
I don't know, everything looks to be in order.
(I did double check my DNS settings and they appear to be fine)

Does anyone know what I should be doing next?

Comment: Have you verified that the .htaccess is being applied at all? In the server-level or `<Directory>` config, you must have an appropriate [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive in order for the .htaccess to be parsed.  The shared host would have done this for you but the VPS may require you to do it yourself.

Comment: To test for HTTPS off, you can just use something simple like `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, yes the htaccess is working as there are other rules in it that do get applied ;)

Comment: Then debug by disabling conditions one at a time.

Comment: I did, both domains, with www and without www remain to be accessible...

Comment: if its a vps just ssh into your server and reconfigure your apache records so that you have ServerAlias as both www and non www part of the domain then you don't need the htaccess any more thats the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @Dave, I'm not yet fully capable of doing that :) Could you tell me how or show me the way to a manual please?

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
Rewriteengine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot the write "rewriteengine on" on top please add and then try

Comment: I saw that, and I added it in my code though... Still, not working.
I think that both domain names are accessible because of a server config...

Comment: I have checked the domain with  non-www and www its redirecting to   www.tx3.be , please clear cache or check another browser.

Comment: @gelleby maybe it's a DNS issue, can you ping your server and get the correct IP ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, yes, I can ping everything and always get the correct IP

Answer (score 0):

If using windows download putty (ssh client) give it your servers ip address select type as ssh and click open.

It'll ask you for a username and password give it your root username and password (should have been provided by vps hosting company)

Now cd through to your apache config folder (I'm only familiar with debian based setups if you're using a redhat based setup you may have to google correct path) /etc/apache2/sites-available

Now look at the directory listings (ls) and it'll show you the apache configs available chances are you'll have something like www.tx3.be in there.  Edit that file I recommend using pico or nano by doing pico

Here's an example off my server

```
root@hinch:/home/hinch# cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
root@hinch:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls
default                   
default-ssl               
root@hinch:/etc/apache2/sites-available# pico default
```

Now you're in your apache config file you'll see something like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin root@yourdomain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm default.htm default.html default.php
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>    
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After the line that says `ServerAdmin` add in the following

```
ServerAlias tx3.be
ServerAlias www.tx3.be
```

Save the file and restart apache

`service apache2 restart` or `service httpd restart`

Delete all redirect code from your .htaccess and make sure you have both the www. dns A record and the @. A record pointing to your servers ip address.  Now regardless of which version of the domain the user goes to they'll see your site.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, could it be that there is a DNS issue at my provider though? Maybe that is why http://tx3.be/ is resolving at my end?

Comment: I know, but I still get that weird page "Apache is functioning normally" without the www

Comment: thats because apache doesn't know how to handle the domain without the www. on the front of it so its being processed by the default apache domain rule. thats why you need to configure apache for your domain to accept your domain without the www. on it hence the ServerAlias lines in your apache config.

Comment: I got an error: 
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
ServerAlias only used in <VirtualHost>

Comment: you added it to the httpd config not the site config. the httpd.conf is purely for the server setup

Comment: I'm running CentOS 5.9 and according to [this site](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout) there is no Default VHost Config on CentOS so I assumed I could change the httpd.conf file as the code is almost the same as yours...

Comment: yeah you could but you'll have to be careful with the syntax but the default should be a catch all. However if your running something like plesk or other web control panel for your vps that may well store the apache configs else where or give you the ability to edit the apache configs within the web interface do a little more digging on google or research serveralias in centos default httpd.conf. Cent is based on redhat where as i'm more familiar with debian based distro's there'll be subtle differences you'll need to research